# queryRaw don't show data on prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

is there prisma developers here?

```js
 const users = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User`;
```

queryraw doesn't work for me, data appear on prisma studio and there is no problem but when I try to run the query above, It only shows my postgres username. When I check my data on psql, It shows the same, tables appear but there is no data inside.

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance for those who'll help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass the database schema name while fetching data through Raw Query.

Like this:

```
 const users = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "public"."User"`;
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

$queryRunUnsafe is function and must be pass sql query as argument

`const users= await prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(query);`

Comment: The problem is the same, there is no data